# Laptop and software too old for Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, wubi, compaq

Just ran through 1-7 steps on this download and install procedure http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows only to fall flat at Step 7.

Computer, a Compaq 6910p laptop running Windows XP, throws up a Boot Manager with only "Windows" and "System Restore" as options, no sign of "Ubuntu".

Is my laptop and software too old for all this or have I missed something?

Comment: Just a reference, this is the Wubi installer you're  using.

Comment: I would recommend installing through live cd/usb not wubi. It will save you quite some time and some problems. (& remember no laptop is too old for running ubuntu)

Comment: It would be useful to try a live cd/usb session (as Ashu suggested). Just make sure you have enough RAM memory (512 MB or more is recommended). You can check the [minimum requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

Comment: Re. the wubi issue, sometimes the problem is an unusually formatted `C:\boot.ini`. I'd try the standalone first, but if you want help with the Wubi part, edit your question and include the boot.ini file.

Comment: Ubuntu versions as recent as 11.10 (see [comment on this site about linux on laptops](http://www.linlap.com/doku.php?id=hp-compaq_6910p#comment_514267a23f490feac9520c052880d51f)) are reported to work out-of-the-box on that Compaq. Still, you always have [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

Comment: Including the specifications of your laptop would help us help you. as carnendil has pointed out Lubuntu is a very lightweight version of ubuntu which will run on very limited hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the specs as reviewed [here](http://www.cnet.com/products/hp-compaq-6910p/) (which may not match your particular system) you should have no problem running Ubuntu. For maximum performance you may want to consider the lighter versions Lubuntu or Xubuntu. Here's a by no means exhaustive rundown of system requirements ranging from heaviest to lightest so that you can choose the best flavor for you!

[Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/requirements/)

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/blog/lubuntu-1404-trusty-tahr-released)

Comment: You may also wish to review this (had I found it earlier I could have saved some time). http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop